# cant download file having special characters in name using download manager class in android

Tags: android

ive tried without "-" symbol sigh that time it worked fine but with this file can't download file from my server
here is my code

```
Button b1,b2;
String dwnload_file_path = "http://www.drvrgit.com/0APK/BCA/T-1 Java History, Introduction, Basics.doc";
DownloadManager downloadManager;
b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);   
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(dwnload_file_path);
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                //request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"IOStreams.pdf");

                Long referance = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

            }
        });
```

Comment: what's the response you receive from server?

Comment: you could try to force download manager to use UTF8 encoding assuring also server side code use the same